# Struggling with proving an elementary atomic equation. Please critique my proof.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

I am learning how to prove and disprove atomic equations. I have put together a proof where I know how I want to prove the theorem but can't quite get it to flow correctly. Please critique my syntax, flow, or anything else as I am learning how to prove mathematical statements:

\begin{align*}
    & \hspace{5mm} \textbf{Assume: }x,y \text{ are arbitrary, non-zero real numbers} && \\
    & \hspace{5mm} \textbf{Goal: } \text{Prove: }\exists y : ( \forall x \not = 0 : xy = 1)) \text{ is False.} && \\
    & \hspace{10mm} \textbf{Expanded Goal: } \forall k \in \mathbb{R}_{\not = 0} : (x+k)y = 1 \text{ is a contradiction}&& \\
    & \hspace{15mm} \textbf{Scratch Work} \\
    & \hspace{20mm} (x+k)y = 1 \\
    & \hspace{20mm} xy + ky = 1 \\
    & \hspace{20mm} \text{Recall: }xy = 1 \\
    & \hspace{20mm} \therefore 1 + ky = 1 \\
    & \hspace{20mm} \therefore ky = 0 \\ 
    & \hspace{20mm} \because y = \frac{1}{x} \\ 
    & \hspace{20mm} \therefore \frac{k}{x} = 0 \\
    & \hspace{20mm} \because x \not = 0 \\ 
    & \hspace{20mm} \therefore k = 0 \\ 
    & \hspace{20mm} \bot \\ 
\end{align*}

Conclusion: $k = 0$ when $k$ is a real number, defined as a constant added to $x$. Thus, the theorem is proved, as the only way to make the theorem valid is to add an identity element to $x$.

I also constructed this: \begin{align*}
    & \text{Theorem: } \exists y : ( \forall x \not = 0 : xy = 1)) \text{ where } x,y \in \mathbb{R} \\
    & \text{Goal: } \bot \\
    & \hspace{5mm} \text{We know: } xy = 1 \equiv y = 1/x \\
    & \hspace{5mm} \text{Let $k \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary and non-identity} \\
    & \hspace{5mm} \text{Multiplication is possible in this algebra} \\
    \therefore \hspace{2mm} & \hspace{10mm} \text{Let $x$ be multiplied by $k$} \\
    & \hspace{10mm} \text{By the reflexive property: } yk = k/x \\
    & \hspace{10mm} \text{But } k/y \not = y \text{ because } k \text{ is a non-identity element} \\
    \therefore \hspace{2mm} & \bot
\end{align*}

Do either of these make any sense? Again, I feel like I know what I want to say, I am just struggling to say it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be more natural ways to prove that "$\exists y \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}: (\forall x \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}, xy = 1)$" is False. This could be contributing to why the proofs you presented feel less succinct or satisfying to you. Also, depending on the level of formality expected for the proof, your writing style could be overly formal (seeing "atomic equations" in your question makes me feel this is not the case though). I will present two options, the first structured as a proof by contradiction that the theorem is False and the second as a direct proof of the negation of the theorem. I will write them in a less formal style, although they could always be made more formal.

Striving for a contradiction, assume that "$\exists y \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}: (\forall x \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}, xy = 1)$" is True. This should be understood as saying that there is some $y \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ (that we do not otherwise have any information about) with the property that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$, $xy=1$. Now, let $a \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ be arbitary. By the defining property of $y$, we require that $ay=1$. We will now construct some $b \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ that does not have $by=1$, as the defining property of $y$ would require, and hence arrive at a contradiction since $\exists b \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}:by\neq1$. Consider $b=2a$ and note that since $a,2 \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$, we also have that $b \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ since $\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ is closed under multiplication. But $by=(2a)y=2(ay)=2(1)=2\neq 1$. Therefore, we have constructed some $b \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}:by\neq1$, completing the proof of $\perp$. Note that we did not have to use $2$, in particular, over any non-identity $k \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$, but that fixing $k$ is still sufficient for arriving at a contradiction.

We will now prove "$\forall y \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}, (\exists x \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}:xy \neq 1)$" is True. Let $y \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ be arbitrary. Our job is to now construct some $x \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ such that $xy \neq 1$. Consider $x=2y^{-1}$, where $y^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $y$ satisfying $yy^{-1}=y^{-1}y=1$. Note that $y^{-1} \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ since $y \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ is closed under multiplicative inverses. Moreover, $x=2y^{-1} \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ since $2,y^{-1} \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ is closed under multiplication. Then we have $xy=(2y^{-1})y=2(y^{-1}y)=2(1)=2 \neq 1$. We have shown that $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}:xy \neq 1$, completing the proof that the negation of the theorem is True. Once again, $2$ could be replaced by any non-identity $k \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ but this is not necessary to reach the conclusion.

A note about your first proof: the contradiction reached against the statement in the expanded goal can be used to conclude that $\exists k \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ such that $(x+k)y \neq 1$. The existence of this $k$ is not surprising since under the original contradiction hypothesis that $xy=1$, the statement "$\forall k \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$, $(x+k)y \neq 1$" is True. Having only shown $\exists k \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ such that $(x+k)y \neq 1$ is actually problematic in this case because, for example if $k=-x$, $x+k = 0 \notin \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ and thus $(x+k)y \neq 1$ no longer contradicts $\exists y \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}: (\forall x \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}, xy = 1)$. The important point here is that the contradiction of the expanded goal, which shows $\exists k \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ such that $(x+k)y \neq 1$, does not necessarily give rise to a contradiction of the original contradiction hypothesis. Therefore, the first proof is technically invalid as written (although it comes from a good idea and can quickly be corrected by rewriting the expanded goal as $\forall k \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}\setminus{\{-x\}}$, $(x+k)y=1$). In an existential statement like "$\exists A$ such that $B$", always be aware that the provided $A$, besides satisfying $B$, is otherwise unconstrained and may be exactly what you would not like it to be.

In your second proof, $k$ being a non-identity element does not entail $\frac{k}{y} \neq y$. A counterexample is $k=4$ and $y=2$. It is also unclear how "Let $x$ be multiplied by $k$" is being used since the next line seems to come from $ky=ky$. Perhaps you meant this and also $\frac{k}{x} \neq y$. What seems to need to be done here is not let $k$ be so arbitrary; restrict it to $\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0} \setminus{\{x\}}$. This will allow you to show $\exists x' \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}: x'y \neq 1$, namely $x'=k$, and arrive at a contradiction to complete your proof.

Otherwise, I think you did a great job reminding yourself of what you want to show by writing the goal and accurately using quantifiers. The line-by-line scratch work is also well organized. The second proof needs a little cleaning up but is close. I hope this was helpful and want to encourage you to keep honing your proof-writing skills! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, I appreciate it. There are "small" syntax differences that can make a huge difference, which I'm still trying to get better at, like any language. I will digest what you wrote and make sure I understand it.